# Meld requires pygtk 2.8.0 or higher

Tags: python, svn, diff, pygtk, meld

I need a diff tool to use with svn, found meld already installed, set-up rapid-svn to use it, but when I right-click and select diff, nothing happened. so tried meld on command to see if it works:

```
gunselic@gezxx:~$ meld
No module named pygtk
Meld requires pygtk 2.8.0 or higher.
```

So I googled it and found pygtk was python-gtk2:

```
gunselic@gezxx:~$ sudo apt-get install python-gtk2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-gtk2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
```

I tried pip install, reistall uninstall etc.
I work with Ubuntu 10.04.4 on Oracle VM Virtualbox, and I m using an already configured image because of the project I m working on, is there any way to get meld working on this one? Thanks,
Gunseli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 versions of pythons installed, under usr/bin and usr/local/bin. I renamed the one under usr/local/bin, and it's resolved.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sudo vi $(which meld)
```

Edit the first line to use python2.6 as follows

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.6
```

Save and exit. Enter `:wq` in vi

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I had the same issue, where the Python referred in the env was custom one [Python 2.6 on differrent path].

When I tried the followign it works. So change the appropriate installed python.

**/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/meld**